# Swift Xib UiView BottomSheet being called multiple times

Tags: swift, uiview, xib

so i make this bottomsheet view with xib and theres nothing wrong with my code, its just i only want to show it once, i mean like everytime i click the button its get triggered. which is fine but if i rapidly click the button it will also load bunch of time according on how many times i click. i only want to show once i mean no matter how much you rapidly click it only gonna show the xib view once, until i dismiss the button on the xib and it will do the same thing.

here's some video to make it more clearly

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12pwGdTiP_1QZlYc8tV-BlIIQQ5yYrfto/view?usp=sharing

i put a gif on that gdrive link

for the code

Xib Controller :

```
OrderActionSheetView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Text: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var vieww: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var botView: UIView!
@IBAction func cobaLagiBTn(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let closeView = screenSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        let frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: closeView, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        
    })
}


let fullView: CGFloat = 0
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    

    
    vieww.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    vieww.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    vieww.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:222/255, green:225/255, blue:227/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    vieww.clipsToBounds = true
    
    botView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    botView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    botView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.14
    botView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    botView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.7
    
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
        let frame = self?.view.frame

        let yComponent = self?.fullView
        self?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yComponent!, width: frame!.width, height: frame!.height)
    }
}

func prepareBackgroundView(){
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect.init(style: .light)
    let visualEffect = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: blurEffect)
    let bluredView = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: blurEffect)
    bluredView.contentView.addSubview(visualEffect)

    visualEffect.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    bluredView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

    view.insertSubview(bluredView, at: 0)
}



func Show(){
    
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
    }
 }
```

View Controller :

```
class BottomSheetViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let text = "Connection Failed"
     addBottomSheetView(text: text)
    
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}



func addBottomSheetView(text : String) {
    // 1- Init bottomSheetVC
    let bottomSheetVC = OrderActionSheetView()
    
    // 2- Add bottomSheetVC as a child view
    self.addChild(bottomSheetVC)
    self.view.addSubview(bottomSheetVC.view)
    bottomSheetVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    
    // 3- Adjust bottomSheet frame and initial position.
    let height = view.frame.height
    let width  = view.frame.width
    bottomSheetVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.maxY, width: width, height: height)
    
    bottomSheetVC.Text.text = text
    }

 }
```

i just need to know how to stop popping up twice, cause its kinda really some big bugs.....

like i said earlier i just want the xib view to shown only once no matter how many times you rapidly click the button.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As here you add a new instance every click

```
func addBottomSheetView(text : String) {
   // 1- Init bottomSheetVC
   let bottomSheetVC = OrderActionSheetView()

   // 2- Add bottomSheetVC as a child view
   self.addChild(bottomSheetVC)
   self.view.addSubview(bottomSheetVC.view)
    bottomSheetVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

So either

1-You need to add a bool variable like

```
 var isShown = false
```

and in beginning of method add this code

```
guard !isShown else { return }
isShown = true
```

and when you remove the view make

```
isShown = false
```

Or

2- create an instance variable like

```
var bottomSheetVC:OrderActionSheetView?
```

and in beginning of method

```
guard bottomSheetVC == nil else { return }
bottomSheetVC = OrderActionSheetView()
```

and when you remove it do

```
bottomSheetVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
bottomSheetVC = nil
```

Comment: so i should use either of your way inside my addBottomSheetView()?

Comment: i try to add guard !isShown inside the addBottomSheetView func and i try to call the false after i press the button to dismiss, but still called multiple times and pop up multiple times, or maybe i put it wrong?

Comment: in both cases above create a variable to hold a reference to the added view and use most bottom code to remove it when you set `isShown = false` or better use option 2 in answer

Comment: ahh okay so i make a global var isnt it? i use your 1st option and it works like a charm, but now you said option 2 is better.....so should i use option 1 or 2 for big project?

Comment: option 2 has advantage of 1 instance variable instead of 2

Comment: ahhh okayy, but i have this error of " has no member 'removeFromSuperview "